# Sign of lagrange multiplier for inqueality constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

As far as I know, the sign of the lagrange multiplier doesn't matter if you use equality constraints. Does it matter for inequality constraints though (for example depending if you formulate them in terms of being greater equal than / lesser equal than zero)?

Comment: You may want to look at the [Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions)

Comment: So It depends on whether I am maximizing or minimizing my objective AND in terms of the formulation of the constraint?

Comment: Yes I think so. Maximizing and lesser than 0 -> non negative multiplier. Then change the sign if you change "maximizing" or "lesser than 0".